# How to find how many site colections are active in a web application using console application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, console-application

I need to retreive how many sites are active in a web application using either powershell code or console application. Require the code ( also need how many users have accessed the active site collections if possible)?

Comment: What is active in your scenario?

Comment: And is Site an SPSite or SPWeb?

Comment: i need to find how many site collections are in active state based on last 10 users who logged in the site

Comment: @priya you should edit your question in order to make it clearer and include this precise requirement

Comment: i need to find out how many site collections in a web application are in active state. By finding out how many users have accessed the individual sites recently (i.e also want to retreive last 10 users who logged in to the sites in the webapplication)

Comment: Quick question, does it need to be code-based? You could utilize web analytics, if I'm not mistaken. Please see the following: http://sportstoday.us/technology/sharepoint-2010---monitoring-and-reporting---viewing-web-analytics-reports.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about active site collections, but to list all your site collections in a specific web application, run PowerShell as admin and type

```
  Get-SPWebApplication http://yourApp/ | Get-SPSite
```

If you got a lot of site collections in a web application you can add the parameter `-limit all` to `get-spsite`.

About the last 10 users who visited the site collection, check your old post.

[How to retreive last 10 users who have logged in a site using Power shell script?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88470/how-to-retreive-last-10-users-who-have-logged-in-a-site-using-power-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define what you mean by Active. If it is simply viewing a site then it is difficult but if it is some edit been done in the site then you should try to use `SPWeb.LastItemModifiedDate` to get the date any item was modified in the site and based on the return date you can judge whether the site has been active or not.